# XMLstarlet not finding elements within an xml file

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to edit a xml file within a Jboss application with XMLstarlet however, XMLstarlet doesn't seem to be able pick up any of the elements within. Would someone be able to help me? I'm trying to edit some of the elements within  however, it can't even find it.

I have a link to the xml file i put on github as its too long to post here:

https://github.com/hliang12/XML/blob/master/domain.xml

Even with the name space inputted:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N x="urn:jboss:domain:2.0" -t -v "count(/server-groups)"  domain.xml
```

This is just an example of trying to select the server-group, is this correct maybe I have put made some error with the syntax

Comment: You forgot to pay attention to the default namespace in your XML. `xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:2.0"`

Comment: Hi @Tomalak I have added the name space part in my select just to test it out,      xmlstarlet sel -N x="urn:jboss:domain:2.0" -t -v "count(/server-groups)"  domain.xml               <- I still get 0 am i doing something wrong? Also is there a way to autonomously get the name space using xmlstarlet or any other way?

Comment: Yes, you are still doing something wrong. `-N` declares namespace prefixes, but you have to use them in your XPath, too.

Comment: Would you be able suggest how I would do that please? I'm not too familiar with xpaths

Comment: The answer in the duplicate question shows how to do this. Look closely.